# Yes/No unchecked magento in module

Tags: database, magento, module, entity-attribute-value

I'm working with some module and I must add new column to my database.
1) I modified edit form:

```
$fieldset->addField("temporary", "select", array(
    "label" => Mage::helper("my_helper")->__("Temporarily unavailable"),
    "name" => "temporary",
    'values' => 
    Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno')->toOptionArray(),
));
```

2) I add new column to grid:

```
$this->addColumn("temporary", array(
    "header" => Mage::helper("my_helper")->__("Temporarily unavailable"),
    "index" => "temporary",
    "type" => "options",
    "options" => Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno')->toArray(),
));
```

At the end I run my script na update extension version in config.xml

```
Mage::log(__FILE__ . '::start');
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();
$tableName = $installer->getTable('my_extension/designer');
$installer->getConnection()
    ->addColumn($tableName, 'temporary', array(
    'type' => Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_BOOLEAN,
    'default' => 0,
    'length' => null,
    'nullable' => false,
    'comment' => 'temporary'
));
$installer->endSetup();
Mage::log(__FILE__ . '::end');
```

After that everything works perfectly until, I want to change temporary value "temporary". If I check it once as "Yes" i can't change it back to "No".

Any Ideas

Answer (score 0):

It might be a cache problem.
You need to clear cache through admin System -> Cache Management (Flush Magento Cache and Flush Cache Storage buttons). Magento likes to cache previous queries so adding new fields without clearing the cache can cause problems with new columns not being saved.